# black area above navigation bar appears when search bar is not active?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a search controller added to navigationController.searchController. When the screen initially loads there is a black space above the navigation bar. Only when I tap on the search bar this space correctly shows white. When I tap off the search bar, this area shows black again.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import InstantSearch

class AlgoliaViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {



let userHitsInteractor: HitsInteractor<User> = .init(infiniteScrolling: .off, showItemsOnEmptyQuery: false)
let businessHitsInteractor: HitsInteractor<Business> = .init(infiniteScrolling: .off, showItemsOnEmptyQuery: false)

let multiSearch = MultiIndexSearcher(appID: APP_ID, apiKey: APP_KEY, indexNames: ["dev_USERS","dev_BUSINESS"])
lazy var multiConnector: MultiIndexSearchConnector = .init(searcher: multiSearch, indexModules: [
    .init(indexName: "dev_USERS",
          hitsInteractor: userHitsInteractor),
    .init(indexName: "dev_BUSINESS",
          hitsInteractor: businessHitsInteractor)
  ], searchController: searchController, hitsController: hitsTableViewController)


  lazy var searchController: UISearchController = .init(searchResultsController: hitsTableViewController)




let hitsTableViewController = MultiIndexController()
  let statsInteractor: StatsInteractor = .init()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    multiConnector.connect()
    multiSearch.search()
    statsInteractor.connectController(self)
    setupUI()
}

func setupUI() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
    
//        navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
    
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.showsSearchResultsController = true
    searchController.automaticallyShowsCancelButton = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    
    
    
    hitsTableViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchController.isActive = true
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchController.isActive = false
}



}

extension AlgoliaViewController: StatsTextController {


  func setItem(_ item: String?) {
title = item
  }
}








class MultiIndexController: UITableViewController, MultiIndexHitsController {
var hitsSource: MultiIndexHitsSource?

let cellID = "cellID"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(ResultsItemCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    setupUI()

    self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
}

func setupUI() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return (hitsSource?.numberOfSections())!
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return (hitsSource?.numberOfHits(inSection: section)) ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
    let sectionTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width, height: headerView.frame.height))
    Utilities.styleLblFont(sectionTitle, fontName: "Cabin-SemiBold", fontSize: 18, color: .black)
    var headertitle = ""
    switch section {
    case 0:
        print("section 0")
        headertitle = "People"
    case 1:
        print("section 1")
        headertitle = "Businesses"
    default:
        break
    }
    headerView.backgroundColor = .white
    sectionTitle.text = headertitle
    headerView.addSubview(sectionTitle)
    return headerView
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID) as! ResultsItemCell
    
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        if let item: User = try? hitsSource?.hit(atIndex: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section) {
            cell.nameLbl.text = item.userName
            cell.avatar.loadImage(item.profilePhotoUrl)
            cell.jobTitleLbl.text = item.userType
      }
      
    case 1:
        if let business: Business = try? hitsSource?.hit(atIndex: indexPath.row, inSection: indexPath.section) {
            cell.nameLbl.text = business.businessName
            cell.avatar.loadImage(business.businessAvatarUrl)
            cell.jobTitleLbl.text = business.mission
      }
    default:
        break
    }
     
    return cell
    
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
    let seeResultsBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: footerView.frame.width, height: footerView.frame.height))
    var footerTitle = ""
    switch section {
    case 0:
        footerTitle = "See all people"
    case 1:
        footerTitle = "See all businesses"
    default:
        footerTitle = "See all results"
    }
    
    footerView.addSubview(seeResultsBtn)
    seeResultsBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    seeResultsBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    seeResultsBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    Utilities.buttonTitle(seeResultsBtn, title: footerTitle, titleColour: .jabiMain, fontName: "Cabin-Medium", fontSize: 16)
    footerView.backgroundColor = .white
    return footerView
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}




}
```

Please see the screenshots:

[image: before tapping search bar]

[image: when search bar is active]

Comment: Include enough code for a [mre]. Otherwise, this is extremely unlikely to be debuggable.

Comment: @jnpdx just added the code too